# Find coefficients for which two random variables are independent

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

> Find all pairs of $(a, b)$, such that $$W_{1} + a \cdot W_{3}$$ and $$b \cdot W_{2} - W_{4}$$ are independent.
>   $W$ is a standard Wiener process.

Is it sufficient to check if the expected value of XY equals the product of expected value of X and Y, where X, Y are the variables from the problem?